# Question on lemma 38.1 from Munkres book

Tags: general-topology

I was reading this lemma from Munkres book and I spent some time in order to understand some of the moments but failed to do it.

**Question 1.** We have to show that $X$ is a subspace of $Y$. What does it mean? In my opinion we have to show that subspace topology of $X$ inherited from $Y$ is the same as the original topology on $X$, right? Author says that $H|_X=h$ (this is obvious) but I do not know how to use it in order to show that $X$ is a subspace of $Y$.

**Question 2.** We have the homeomorphism $H:Y\to Y_0$ where $\overline{X_0}=Y_0$ then how it follows that $\overline{X}=Y$?

I would be very grateful if anyone will give detailed answers to my question.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So by definition $Y=X\cup A$ (disjoint union) and the topology on $Y$ is given by $U \subseteq Y$ open iff $H[U]$ open in $Y_0$. This is a well-defined topology because $H$ is a bijection of $Y$ with $Y_0$: it's the combination of a bijection $h$ between $X$ and $X_0$ and another bijection $k$ between the disjoint $A$ and $Y-Y_0$. And $Y_0$ has a well-defined subspace topology inherited from $Y$ (it's also compact Hausdorff, as $Y$ is) and $H$ is a homeomorphism between $Y$ and $Y_0$ (it's a continuous and open bijection because of the "iff" in the definition of the topology).

And because $X_0$ is dense in $Y_0$, $X$ (the image of $X_0$ under the homeomorphism $H$) is dense in $Y$.

By definition $h$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $X_0$ (in the subspace topology wrt $Y_0$, or equivalently $Y$). So $O \subseteq X$ open iff $h[O]=H[O]$ is open in $X_0$, so iff $H[O] = U \cap X_0$ for some open $U$ of $Y_0$. This $U$ is of the form $H[U']$ with $U'$ open in $Y$ (as $H$ is a homeomorphism) and so $H[O]=H[U' \cap X]$ so $O= U' \cap X$ and $X$ is thus a subspace of $Y$.

Comment: Could you expand your last paragraph? I did not get how it implies that $X$ is a subspace of $Y$

Comment: Moreover, why $H(O)$ is open in $H(X_0)$? Note that $H(X_0)$ does not make sense

Comment: @ZFR I was a bit sloppy at the end; should be better now.

Comment: Right now it is much better! Thanks a lot for your permanent help!

Comment: BTW let me ask you one more question on this lemma: The author takes the set $A$ which is disjoint from $X$ and such that $A$ is in bijective correspondence with  the set $Y_0-X_0$? Why such $A$ should exist? I was thinking that one can take $A=Y_0-X_0$ but in this case it may not be disjoint with $X$.

Comment: For any sets $A$ and $B$ there is always is a set $A'$ in bijection with $A$ that is disjoint from $B$: e.g. try $A'= A \times \{x\}$ for any set $x$, there must be some  $x$ so that this product is disjoint from $B$ (because we have more possible $x$ then there are elements of $B$...). This is quite a general point in set theory. The idea is that we have $X$ embedded into $Y$ and Munkres wants a compactification that contains $X$ as a subset (and subspace), so we have to "transport" $h[X]$ and its remainder in $Y_0$ back to a $X \cup A$ situation...

Comment: In your above example I see that $A'$ in bijection with $A$. But why it should be disjoint from $B$? Could you give more detailed answer, please? It seems correct intuitively but...

Comment: @ZFR it cannot intersect $B$ for every choice of a set $x$, or $B$ would be as big as the set theory universe. This cannot happen in standard ZFC set theory.

Comment: By Russel's paradox, right? Because there is no BIG set in ZFC, more precisely the set of all sets.

Comment: @ZFR Russell’s paradox plays a part yes. And there is no set of ordinals either. They are too big to be a set.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not familiar with ordinals at all

Comment: @ZFR you don’t need to be. Munkres does cover parts of that theory because he needs $\Omega$ as an example.

Comment: I know the definition of $\Omega$ which was in the Munkres book. But I cannot understand how it relates to my question? $S_{\Omega}$ is minimal uncountable well-ordered set.

Answer (score 2):

X is a subspace of Y means that X is a subset of Y and that X has the topology
{ U $\cap$ X : U open subset of Y }.

Comment: Ok. I see that $X$ is a subset of $Y$. But what about the second property? How to prove it in my case?